# Do-while loop ends program before while statement is met

Tags: java, object, arraylist, do-while

Right now, I'm writing a program that will allow a user to create an infinite number of exercise objects, and will only stop when the user input is equal to certain a value. Below is the relevant code:

```
String s = "";
do {
        UserAddedExercise();
        System.out.print("Do you want to add another exercise? (Y/N) ");
        s = in.nextLine();
} while(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

```
public static void UserAddedExercise() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the exercise name: ");
        String exe = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the location for the exercise: ");
        String loc = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter if the exercise is weighted or not: ");
        String w = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the the muscle location exercised: ");
        String ml = in.nextLine();
        Exercise e = new Exercise(exe,loc,w,ml);
    }
```

Here is the entire exercise constrcutor

```
/*
Constructor class for creating new exercises. Currently, the getter methods are redundant, but I'm leaving them in
case I decide to use them in some way in the future. No default constructor is needed
 */
public class Exercise {
    private String exercise;
    private String location;
    private String weighted;
    String muscleLocation;

    public Exercise(String newExercise, String newLocation, String newWeighted, String newMuscleLocation){
        this.exercise = newExercise;
        //Three options: Home, Gym, Both
        this.location = newLocation;
        //Three Options: Yes, No, Optional
        this.weighted = newWeighted;
        //Multiple Option: Biceps, Triceps, Calves, etc.
        this.muscleLocation = newMuscleLocation;
    }
    //Setter methods for the 4 current parameters for
    public void setExercise(String newExercise){ this.exercise = newExercise; }
    public void setLocation(String newLocation){ this.location = newLocation; }
    public void setWeighted(String newWeighted){ this.weighted = newWeighted; }
    public void setMuscleLocation(String newMuscleLocation){ this.muscleLocation = newMuscleLocation; }
    public String getExercise(){
        return this.exercise;
    }
    public String getLocation(){
        return this.location;
    }
    public String getWeighted(){
        return this.weighted;
    }
    public String getMuscleLocation(){
        return this.muscleLocation;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("\n\t%s, %s, %s, %s", exercise, location, weighted, muscleLocation);
    }


}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the `UserAddedExercise()` method properly executes in the do-while loop, and the print statement is printed out, however the program automatically exits after the statement has been printed out, preventing user input. The exercise objects will later be added to an ExerciseSet ArrayList, but I want to get this solved first, and to understand WHY it is my program exits the do-while loop. Thank you.

Comment: It might be because you're create a new `Scanner` in `UserAddedExercise`. Try using a single one throughout the whole program.

Comment: You don't need the `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` in `UserAddedExercise()` if you can access the `in` that you are using in the loop from within `UserAddedExercise()`

Comment: Does the `Exercise` constructor itself do any user input?

Comment: To answer some questions: @Dan W and @JustAnotherDeveloper : That was the correct solution that someone answered below, however on their code they didn't remove it from the `UserAddedExercise()` method. @Dawood ibn Kareem, are you referring to if the actual constructor class takes any input besides the method shown?

Comment: You haven't shown the constructor for `Exercise`.  Does it use a `Scanner` at all to take user input?  If it does, that might explain what's happening for you.  It's hard to diagnose a problem, and therefore impossible to provide a proper answer to the question, when you have only shown a portion of the code.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The solution below solved the problem by just making the scanner accessible to the whole class, and not just a single method. I will provide the scanner however, as you are correct, I did not include the constructor when I should have, so that was my bad. Maybe you have a better solution as well.

Comment: OK, so the constructor doesn't use a `Scanner`.  That's good.  I'm a little surprised that the solution by Whatever22 works for you, but if it does work, that's good too.  I was expecting to see that there was some additional data that you had tried to read at some point, but I guess that wasn't the case.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, my thoughts exactly, but now for some reason, with the UserAddedExercise method, the first two print statements are printed and not just the first, if that makes sense. I’m just going to ask about that at a later date if I can’t get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to previous comments, try something like this:

```
public class MainClass{

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "";
        do
        {
            UserAddedExercise();
            System.out.print("Do you want to add another exercise? (Y/N) ");
            s = in.nextLine();
        } while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        in.close();
     }

     public static void UserAddedExercise(){
        System.out.print("Enter the exercise name: ");
        String exe = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the location for the exercise: ");
        String loc = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter if the exercise is weighted or not: ");
        String w = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the the muscle location exercised: ");
        String ml = in.nextLine();
        Exercise e = new Exercise(exe, loc, w, ml);
    }
 }

class Exercise{

     public Exercise(String exe, String loc, String w, String ml){
     }
}
```

Comment: That worked for solving the issue I had previously, however now, for some reason, in the `UserAddedExercise()` method, the first two print statements print at the same time.